# R as.Date conversion century error

Tags: r, date

In my dataset a column contains Date of Births of many employees so many of them lies in the range 1960 to 1980. I am trying to format them using as.Date and in some of them the results are not per my expectation.

Example:

```
as.Date("7/1/61","%m/%d/%y")
```

i want it to return "1961-07-01" but it returns "2061-07-01".

Answer (score 2):

Read:

```
?strptime  # where all the formatting details are available
```

> %y
>   Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behavior specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

So you need a regex to backdate and it's probably better to do as a string conversion before sending to as.Date:

```
dvec <- c("7/1/61", "7/1/79")
as.Date(  sub("/(..$)", "/19\\1",dvec)  , "%m/%d/%Y")
 [1] "1961-07-01" "1979-07-01"
```

If this goes into production it will become an error waiting to happen when the age of your employees starts to creep above the last two digits of the current year.

Comment: I think the POSIX committee should disallow two-digit years and scrap the %y format. Its not like we need to save ink these days...

Comment: Yeah, that would be awesome for those data scientists who cannot influence their data source and are being served periodically with a `yy-mm-dd` format... I speak from experience, never disallow a two-digit year. I think the `as.Date` function should have an optional parameter to set this.